# Cost and long lasting configuration using MySQL vs MongoDB on customers records

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a dataset of 5 million customers where READ is the most critical operation. Each customer record contains typical personal information.

What are the approximate hardware requirements/usages when using:

- MySQL
- MongoDB

I need to figure out a solution that will be long-lasting.

Thanks ahead for your answers.

Comment: This question is not about programming, but Stack Overflow requires that questions about about specific code problems. Questions about infrastructure are not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Even if Stack Overflow were the right site for such a question, there isn't enough information to provide an accurate answer. No example queries, no specific description of how much data per customer, no details about traffic rate or acceptable performance, etc. I think the only way to answer your question is to direct you to run load tests and add more system resources until you're satisfied.

Comment: I've moved it to serverfault.com, Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For this work, recommend use MongoDB,because activity predominant is reading, since mongo has no relationship between its collections. When you query a data you do not have the burden of looking for its relationships. the difference is noticeable when querying a large amount of data. I hope it helps you, and I leave you with information that can be of great help to you in the future:
https://www.ml4devs.com/articles/datastore-choices-sql-vs-nosql-database/

Comment: The main reason I'm not so sure about MongoDB is the high usage of memory that will make it significantly more costly than MySQL. What do you think about that?

Comment: At that point it depends on what you're willing to pay, the best alternative for this problem is mongoDB, but I couldn't tell you if the performance you get is enough to pay those extra dollars. I would need much more data, functionalities, quality attributes to give a more accurate opinion on this case. With the data you gave me, I could tell you to opt for performance as long as it is profitable and it is what you need! Take this opinion carefully and I invite you to continue investigating